# Cannot see dropdown for "use this report as a subreport" option

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to use a subreport in my master report (local). However, I don't see a dropdown to select the subreport but instead see a textbox. Relative path doesn't work either. What am I missing here?
[image]

Note: It is mandatory for me that both master and subreport must be in different folders.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the master report saved already? That might help the report designer detect possible sub reports. If it doesn't know where the master report is saved, finding sub reports is not possible.

Comment: Yes, that is saved and I even built the solution

Comment: And there are other reports in this solution?

Comment: Yes in different folders but same project.

Comment: That's rather odd. You should have a "Browse..." button next to the subreport textbox. What version of Report Builder are you on? Have you tried just typing the path fully eg "/Folder1/SubFolder1/SubReports/Header"?